# NetBeans Platform App - Window control

Tags: java, netbeans, platform

I'm learning the NetBeans Platform and I've gone through a few tutorials and started working on a app.  I've implemented the login tutorial with some changes which include 3 levels of access for a text editing application.  The access levels are User, Admin, and None.  Based on access level different options will be available.  If the user has None, then I want to stop the window from opening and instead present a dialog indicating they don't have permission to use the module.  I can't figure out how to keep the window from loading.  The permissions check is within the top component constructor but I don't know how to make the window self-close.

I tried doing an immediate return from the constructor but that leaves an empty tab in the editor area.  I've tried this.close(), variations on trying to get the WindowManager, etc., with no luck.

How can I make the window either not open or close immediately?

Comment: As a follow-up, it might be more prudent to do the authority check when the menu item is clicked and avoid the call to the top component altogether but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Call `this.close()` in the `componentActivated()` method of the top component. Make sure to call `super.componentActivated();` before calling `this.close()`